# How can I reach a property of an object in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have that problem: I'm trying to reach the property of on object "user" that I save in localStorage and the browser gives me the error "Cannot read properties of undefined".
I apply my code

```js
 like(recipe) {
        if (this.favorites.indexOf(recipe) === -1) {
            this.favorites.push(recipe)
        }
        let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
        let currFav = user.favorites;
        currFav.push(recipe);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(user))
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for "user" or "users"?

Comment: You don't seem to take into account that `users` isn't set in local storage yet. What should happen in that case? But I think `JSON.parse` never actually returns `undefined`, so it's strange (i.e. impossible) that you get that error there. Please provide more information and a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that omission. I already have an object  "users" : "cooked": [], "favorites": [], "name": "Dimitar", "password": "123" in localStorage

Comment: Try `console.log(this.favorites)` and see if that's undefined. That may be the problem

Comment: I tried it. Is's defined.

Comment: You did not say which line triggers the error - that would help

Comment: currFav.push(recipe); -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')